# Cannot Deserialize XML File into a List

Tags: c#, xml

My problem is, my program isn't taking data from my XML file and putting it into a list

I can save data just fine but I can't load it back.

Here is my Save function

```
    public void Save_Data_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        XmlSerializer PSR = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Pickup));
        XmlSerializer DSR = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Delivery));

        TextWriter PickupStream = new StreamWriter(@"Pickup Save Data.xml");
        TextWriter DeliveryStream = new StreamWriter(@"Delivery Save Data.xml");
        PSR.Serialize(PickupStream, thePickup);
        DSR.Serialize(DeliveryStream, theDelivery);
        DeliveryStream.Close();
        PickupStream.Close();

        MessageBox.Show("All data saved!");
    }
```

Here is my xml load code

```
  XmlSerializer SerializerObj = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Pickup));
  FileStream ReadFileStream = new FileStream(@"Pickup Save Data.xml", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
  Pickup LoadedObj = (Pickup)SerializerObj.Deserialize(ReadFileStream);
  ReadFileStream.Close();
```

Here is my Pickup Class

```
 namespace Vans
 {
     [Serializable]
     public class Pickup
     {

    public List<Pickups> Pickups = new List<Pickups>();

    public void addPickup(Pickups Pic)
    {
        Pickups.Add(Pic);
    }

    public List<String> listPickups()
    {
        List<String> listPickups = new List<string>();
        foreach (Pickups pick in Pickups)
        {
            String pickupString = pick.ToString();
            listPickups.Add(pickupString);
        }

        return listPickups;

    }

    public Pickups getPickup(int i)
    {

        int c = 0;
        foreach (Pickups Pic in Pickups)
        {
            if (i == c)
                return Pic;
            c++;
        }
        return null;
    }
 }
}
```

My Delivery class is the same as the Pickup class.

Edit

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <Pickup xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"     xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <Pickups>
     <Pickups>
      <pickupfirstname>dsf</pickupfirstname>
      <pickuplastname>sdf</pickuplastname>
      <pickupdeliveryaddress>sd</pickupdeliveryaddress>
      <pickuptime>dsf</pickuptime>
    </Pickups>
  </Pickups>
</Pickup>
```

this is some sample XML code

Comment: What happens when you run your code instead of it working as expected?

Comment: Everything runs, I input some data into my lists, I save it everything is fine...I close the program, it doesn't load back :/

Comment: So you have no exceptions, but after executing the line `Pickup LoadedObj = (Pickup)SerializerObj.Deserialize(ReadFileStream);` the `LoadedObj` variable points to ... what?  Also, can you show the code that calls your load code?

Comment: The load code is called when the program is ran

Comment: Right, I was asking if you could show the code that calls the load code.  It would also help if you could give a sample of the XML.  Hint: the debugger is your friend.  Set a break point on the line `ReadFileStream.Close();` and see what `LoadedObj` points to.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Provide the Pickups class definition to identify the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dsh84875.aspx) example, every field, that should be (de-)serialized, has an annotation `[XmlElement]`, maybe thats the reason...

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your `Pickups` class is as follows to *deserialize* it correctly:

```
public class Pickups
{
    public string pickupfirstname;
    public string pickuplastname;
    public string pickupdeliveryaddress;
    public string pickuptime;
}
```

**Note:** I have tested your code locally with the inclusion of this class and it is working perfectly fine.